# How to describe repeating intervals which has an unfixed time interval in ISO 8601?

Tags: datetime, cron, intervals, iso8601

For example, for the time format which has a fixed time interval, we can describe "**30 9 * * ***"(crontab time format) with "**R/2015-03-01T09:30:00-06:00/P1D**" in **ISO 8601**.

But how can I describe "**10 2,4,6,8,10,14,18,22 * * ***" (which has an unfixed time interval) in ISO 8601?

Thanks a lot!